# How I can change Sender email in "Send an email (V2)" action for more than 80 Power Automate Flows?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, power-automate

I know I can do this by editing flow and finding "Send an email (V2)" action and changing email id from "From (Send as)" property, but to edit more than 80 flows and find "From (Send as)" actions in flow and change email address is tedious job to do. Is there any simple and easy way to do this(using Power Automate or Power Shell)?

Answer (score 2):

Using scripts will make production more difficult, from the perspective of once and for all:
I have two ideas,
The first one: Create a list and create a record for each flow to store emails. Then use the corresponding record in each stream, so that you only need to modify the list when making modifications.
The second method is to use environment variables and create environment variables for each stream.